# Google-meet-api library in react frontend errors

Tags: reactjs

am using an unofficial library called google-meet-api in my front-end react project for generating google meeting link for interviews,but it is giving fs and child-process errors and also
**"export 'default' (imported as 'GoogleMeeting') was not found in 'google-meet-api' (module has no exports)"**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRvh7.png) how can i get rid of these errors.

Comment: can you share " fs and child-process"  errors (),

Comment: index.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Expected `input` to be a `Function` or `Object`, got `undefined`
    at push../node_modules/pify/index.js.module.exports (index.js:45:1)
    at ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js (index.js:22:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)

Comment: I highly suggest to use [this Google Calendar API example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=en#examples) of that library That library uses same example code with slight changes [see here](https://github.com/sumitjangir123/meet-api/blob/master/index.js)  .

Comment: Yes sir even am using the same library,but am getting same error.Can you help me out?

Comment: seems you can't use in client side, I mean you can't use package available in npm, instead you have use script tags to load that package as shown in [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md).